# Routing redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to redirect all requests made to a resource (URL) to another resource.

I have the following resources:

```
<My_app_name>::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :users

    namespace :users do
      resources :user_admins
    end
end
```

What I would like to do is to redirect all requests made to `<my_app_name>/users/user_admins/<id>` to `<my_web_site_name>/users/<id>`. **How can I do that?**

**Note**: I am using a *Single Table Inheritance* approach, so that the `<id>` value will don't change behaviours. That is, the `<id>` value will be automatically handled from the RoR framework and it will refer to the same resource for both when the URL is `<my_app_name>/users/user_admins/<id>` or `<my_web_site_name>/users/<id>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to avoid the use of a namespace, and play it like that :

```
scope "users" do
  resources "user_admins", :controller => "users"
end
```

You'll get those routes :

```
    user_admins GET    /users/user_admins(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                POST   /users/user_admins(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
 new_user_admin GET    /users/user_admins/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user_admin GET    /users/user_admins/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
     user_admin GET    /users/user_admins/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                PUT    /users/user_admins/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                DELETE /users/user_admins/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your routes.rb:

```
match 'users/user_admins/:id' => 'users#show'
```